# Pick last item from list in Powershell

Tags: list, sorting, powershell

I'm trying to map a drive letter using this line of code which will give me a list of drives available from d to z.

```
ls function:[d-z]: -n | ? { !(test-path $_) }
```

I'd like to then pick the last letter, not random, from the list. How would I go about doing that? New to Powershell, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You can use `Select-Object -Last 1` at the end of that pipeline.

Answer (score 22):

you can just start at the back of the list and go up.

last item: `$array[-1]`
Second to last: `$array[-2]`
and so on.

Comment: This feature is called "Subscripting an array" as documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/lang-spec/chapter-07?view=powershell-7.3#7141-subscripting-an-array

Answer (score 9):

If you look for a much more verbose, but (in my opinion) readable-improved version:

```
# Get all drives which are used (unavailable)
# Filter for the "Name" property ==> Drive letter
$Drives = (Get-PSDrive -PSProvider FileSystem).Name

# Create an array of D to Z
# Haven't found a more elegant version...
$Letters = [char[]]([char]'D'..[char]'Z')

# Filter out, which $Letters are not in $Drives (<=)
# Again, filter for their letter
$Available = (Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $Letters -DifferenceObject $Drives | Where {$_.SideIndicator -eq "<="}).InputObject

# Get the last letter
$LastLetter = $Available[-1]
```

Comment: I like this: `$letters = 69..90 | % { [char]$_ }`

Comment: @C.B.: That can be much easier done with `[char[]](69..90)`. No need to drag a pipeline into a simple cast.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
ls function:[d-z]: -n|?{!(test-path $_)} | Select-Object -Last 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option that doesn't require trying all paths from D-Z is to parse `Get-Psdrive`. Here's an example:

```
$lettersInUse = Get-Psdrive | ? { $_.Name.Length -eq 1 } | % { $_.Name }
$lastDriveLetter = [Char]'Z'
while ($lettersInUse -contains $lastDriveLetter) {
  $lastDriveLetter = [Char]($lastDriveLetter - 1)
}
$lastDriveLetter
```

Answer (score 1):

1. In case you have an array

   ```
   $newArray = @(git tag --list)
   $lastmember = $newArray[$newArray.Count – 1]
   ```
2. In case you have a list

   ```
   $newArray | Select-Object -Last 1
   ```