# Is using Select-Object suitable when you don't have access to -Extension?

Tags: powershell, split, powershell-3.0, powershell-v6.0

In Powershell v6, the split-path has the `-Extension` parameter to access the extension of a file name, for example:

```
$pathToResume = "R:\Work\cover.letter_resume_base.odt"
$extension = Split-Path -Extension $pathtoResume
Write-Output $extension # Will print .odt
```

However, Powershell 3 doesn't provide the `-Extension` parameter, but I came up with this solution:

```
# Notice the period between cover and letter
$pathToResume = "R:\Work\cover.letter_resume_base.odt"
$pathToResumeLeaf = Split-Path -Leaf $pathToResume
$pathToResumeLeafArray = $pathToResumeLeaf.Split(".")

$fileExtension = $pathToResumeLeafArray | Select-Object -Last 1
Write-Output $fileExtension # Will print odt
```

I still get the file extension, but without the period. No matter how many periods are in the filename or the length of the array, I will get the same output.

I can't think of any situation where the period is required. If I wanted to print the period with the extension, I can easily add it when I use `Write-Output` or `[string]::format()`

Is `Select-Object` as I've shown above a viable solution when `-Extension` is unavailable?

Comment: if all you want is the last item in an array, the faster & cleaner method is `$Array[-1]` to access the last item in the array. ///// if all you want is the extension from a fileinfo object, use `$FileInfoItem.Extension.Trim('.')` ///// if all you want is the extension part of a filename string, use `$FullFileNameString.Split('.')[-1]`. ///// all of the above will give the `Ext` as a result.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey - Is there anything wrong with `Select-Object`? Its the excepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18018892/pick-last-item-from-list-in-powershell), and it works for me.

Comment: Should be simpler: `$fileExtension = (Get-Item $pathToResume).Extension`

Comment: @LotPings - I like your approach. Is there something wrong with `Select-Object` in this case?

Comment: No, just an additional pipe, to get the last element of an array this is also simpler:  `$fileExtension = "R:\Work\cover.letter_resume_base.odt".Split('.')[-1] `

Comment: Or to keep the dot in the extension with RegEx and a lookahead: `$fileExtension = ("R:\Work\cover.letter_resume_base.odt" -Split '(?=\.)')[-1]`

Comment: @LotPings - doesn't `.Extension` _keep_ the dot? on my win7ps5.1 box, it gives `.Txt` for a text file.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey yes, but the `.split('.')` removes it.

Comment: @nsonline - the problem with Select-Object in this case it two-fold. [1] it requires sending things across the pipeline ... and that is needlessly slow. not much for ONE such, but it mounts up ... and is simply inefficient. [2] the cmdlet is very capable and very generalized ... and that means it does a GREAT DEAL more work than is obvious. the solution i showed is simpler, shorter to type and faster.

Comment: @LotPings - blast![*blush*] i managed to miss that ...sorry for the comment noise.

Comment: Or use .Net `$extension = [System.IO.Path]::GetExtension($pathToResume)`. Also keeps the dot, but unlike `Get-Item` the path does not need to exist. [GetExtension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getextension?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: @GetExtension @Lee_Dailey @LotPings  - For my particular situation the period before the extension doesn't matter, so `.odt` or `odt` is fine. Is it a good practice to keep the period? Are there situations where the period matters?

Comment: @nsonline - since it is part of the standard result, i keep it. that simplifies the code ... and doing unneeded work is ... unneeded. [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey, @LotPings - Is substring okay as well? `$filename = "R:\Work\cover.letter_resume_base.odt".Substring($filename.Length - 4)`. I'm aware it creates a new string representing the substring, is it inefficient?

Comment: @nsonline - the `.SubString()` method is slower than regex stuff, and slower than using `.Extension`. you can test it with `Measure-Command`. however, it is not _vastly slower_ ... so use what fits your way of thinking about the problem. my personal take on getting the extension of a file name ... is to use the code that is built for that - the `[FileInfo]` of a file has that nifty-keano `.Extension` property ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a path *string* as the input, a concise and performant - though a bit obscure - PowerShell-native solution is to use the 
[`-replace` operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40683667/45375) to extract the extension using a [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_regular_expressions):

```
PS> "R:\Work\cover.letter_resume_base.odt" -replace '^.+(\.[^.]+)$', '$1'
.odt
```

<sup>Note: This solution only works reliably if the file path *has* an extension.</sup>

Alternatively, use the .NET framework directly, as [Theo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9898643/theo) suggests:

```
PS> [IO.Path]::GetExtension("R:\Work\cover.letter_resume_base.odt")
.odt
```

You can also cast to `[System.IO.FileInfo]` and access the `.Extension` property:

```
PS> ([IO.FileInfo] "R:\Work\cover.letter_resume_base.odt").Extension
.odt
```

The above is a faster and more flexible alternative to [LotPings](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6811411/lotpings)' `Get-Item` suggestion, which, as Theo points, requires that the file *exist*:

```
# Works, but file must exist.
PS> (Get-Item "R:\Work\cover.letter_resume_base.odt").Extension
.odt
```

---

> Is `Select-Object`, as shown above, a viable solution when `-Extension` is unavailable?

Yes, it is, but it is verbose and slow (though performance may not matter in this case), because using the *pipeline* and *cmdlets* invariably introduces overhead compared to using *expressions* involving *operators*.

LotPings points out that simply indexing with `[-1]` into the results of the `.Split()` call to extract the last token is both more concise and faster.

Also, consider [routinely](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41905031/45375) using PowerShell's `-split` operator instead of the `[string]` type's `.Split()` method:

```
PS> '.' + ("R:\Work\cover.letter_resume_base.odt" -split '\.')[-1]
.odt
```

---

As for whether or not to retain the initial `.` as part of the extension:

Either way, works, as long as you make sure the `.` is there when you synthesize a filename, but retaining the `.` has two advantages:

- looking at the value makes it obvious that you're dealing with an extension
- you can directly append the value to a file's base name (e,g, `$baseName + $ext`), which also works in the case when there's no extension (if `$ext` happens to contain the empty string).

Comment: Thanks for accepting - I've added the comment re retaining the period (`.`) to the answer.